# Linear complexity and quadratic complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o, time-complexity

I'm just not sure...

If you have a code that can be executed in either of the following complexities:

1. A sequence of O(n), like for example: two O(n) in sequence
2. O(n²)

The preferred version would be the one that can be executed in linear time. Would there be a time such that the sequence of O(n) would be too much and that O(n²) would be preferred? In other words, is the statement C x O(n) < O(n²) always true for any constant C?

Why or why not? What are the factors that would affect the condition such that it would be better to choose the O(n²) complexity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there are two issues here; first what the notation says, second what you would actually measure on real programs

1. big O is defiend as a limit as n -> infinity so in terms of big O, O(n) < O(n^2) is always true regardless of any finite constants.
2. as others have pointed out real programs only ever deal with some finite input, so it is quite possible to pick a small enough value for n such that the c*n > n^2 i.e. c > n, however you are strictly speaking no longer dealing with big O

Comment: hmm there seems to be a rendering error that is repeating words in my post?

Comment: @jk It's rendering fine for me.  Also, +1 for the clear answer. :)

Comment: @jk: What do you mean when say you are no longer dealing with big O?

Comment: see point 1, big O strictly speaking only talks about infinite inputs (or the trend as input becomes infinite), clearly no real program that halts does this

Answer (score 2):

If your constant C is greater than your value of n, then the O(n²) algorithm would be better.

Answer (score 1):

There is always an implied constant in O notation, so yes, it's possible that for sufficiently small n that O(n^2) may be faster than O(n). This would happen if the constant for O(n) was much smaller than that for O(n^2).

Comment: You mean the other way around: O(n^2) faster than O(n)

Answer (score 0):

C x O(n) < O(n²) is NOT always true, there is a point in n where it reverses the condition.

When C is large and n is small, then C x O(n) > O(n²).
However, C is always constant, hence when n scales to a large number, C x O(n) < O(n²).

Therefore, when n is large, O(n) is always better than O(n²).