# How to quickly distribute values between collections with ranges

Tags: javascript, algorithm, collections, lodash

Using lodash and javascript. I have two collections, and I'm trying to distribute the values of one of the collections to their associated range in the other collection. My best attempt is shown below at how to tackle this situation, however it quickly runs into what I have come to learn is called a "[quadratic complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771854/linear-complexity-and-quadratic-complexity)" for the time issue. For my function, once I start to get arrays larger than about 20 values, this function takes a noticeable amount of time.

How can I do this faster? Any ideas on how to do this in a linear fashion?

```
var colA = [
    {point: 3, value: 5},
    {point: 10, value: 8},
    {point: 6, value: 18},
    {point: 12, value: 13},
    {point: 11, value: 2},
    {point: 19, value: 4},
    {point: 7, value: 2},
    {point: 8, value: 12},
];


var colB = [
    {min: 1, max: 5, value: 0},
    {min: 5, max: 10, value: 0},
    {min: 10, max: 15, value: 0},
    {min: 15, max: 20, value: 0}
];

_.forEach(colA,function(source){
    var resume = true; 
    _.forEach(colB,function(dest){

        if(resume === true && source.point >= dest.min && source.point < dest.max){
            dest.value += source.value;
            resume = false;
        }
    });
});
```

==== OUTPUT ====

```
var colB = [
    {min: 1, max: 5, value: 5},
    {min: 5, max: 10, value: 32},
    {min: 10, max: 15, value: 23},
    {min: 15, max: 20, value: 4}
];
```

**Note:** This function has been greatly simplified from its current form. This is representative of the basic theory of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: You could sort colA and then find the values within the range for each colB with a binary search - won't be linear, but an improvement

Comment: Yes this is quadratic but I'm surprised that in this day and age it only takes "larger than about **20** values" before "this function takes a noticeable amount of time." Is there a massive overhead involved in function calls in this setup?

Comment: Thanks for your questions - I've added some detail to hopefully clarify what is happening.

Comment: @AakashM Yes, there is a large amount of overhead in this function. As stated in the note below, this is a super simplified version of what is actually taking place - I've tried to strip this down to the key issue that I'm trying to problem solve for.

Comment: are the data and conditions ordered? or orderable?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, the data can be ordered.

Comment: Are the ranges all the same size? You could divide and floor to get the range if so. That is: Math.floor(source.value /5) to get an ID for which range it is in. Then just keep a hash (object) that maps from range ID to the current sum.

Comment: does the range overlap?

Comment: Ranges are exclusive, but are of a variable size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for sorted arrays and non-overlapping ranges, obviously not with lodash.

Array `colA` is just iterated.
Array `colB` is used with an index for the right range. While this array is sorted, the next suitable range is at the actual element or at the following  elements. The while loop end if the index is at the right position or at the end of the array. The following check looks if the element exist and if the value is bigger or equal the min range.

```js
var colA = [{ point: 3, value: 5 }, { point: 10, value: 8 }, { point: 6, value: 18 }, { point: 12, value: 13 }, { point: 11, value: 2 }, { point: 19, value: 4 }, { point: 7, value: 2 }, { point: 8, value: 12 }, ],
    colB = [{ min: 1, max: 5, value: 0 }, { min: 5, max: 10, value: 0 }, { min: 10, max: 15, value: 0 }, { min: 15, max: 20, value: 0 }];

colA.sort(function (k, l) { return k.point - l.point; });
colB.sort(function (k, l) { return k.min - l.min || k.max - l.max; });

colA.reduce(function (i, aa) {
    while (i < colB.length && aa.point > colB[i].max) {
        i++;
    }
    if (colB[i] && colB[i].min <= aa.point) {
        colB[i].value += aa.value;
    }
    return i;
}, 0);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(colB, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Exactly what I was looking for. It took the function I wrote in the OP nearly 5 seconds to iterate 50 times. But with this version, it took less than 250ms. In fact, I had to push it to over 100 before I started to see a measurable increase. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are integers and the range is sensible (not too large).

Define `sums[x]` the sum of all the values from 0 to x. To compute it start from `colA`. For a value `colA[i]` -> sums[colA[i]] += colA[i]. Then run trough sums and add up everything so that it matches the definition.

Now for each element in colB, `value = sums[max - 1] - sums[min - 1]`. (-1 because of the conditions on the bounds).

So now you are O(range + colB + colA) (or the maximum of the 3).

If the range is large, you can still do the same thing, but first normalize the values. That is take all the values in colA, colB.min and colB.max sort and remove duplicates and replace them with their index in the sorted array. It shouldn't matter for the computations, but range becomes integers about as big as the size of colA + colB.

Comment: Ok, your answer seems potentially applicable, but I'm feeling pretty dumb because I'm having a really hard time following the logic. Would you mind writing a sample of what that code would look like?

Comment: Also, for your assumptions - it is safe to assume that the values are integers, but unsafe to assume the range is not too large. I'm actually dealing with UTC timestamp values, and the ranges can actually be quite large.

Comment: If you use timestamps, do the normalization.

Comment: I'm not great with javascript. You should have have a vector sums that looks initially like 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 18, 2, 12, 0, 8 (based on the points <= 10 from your example) that you then add up to get 0,0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 23, 25, 37, 37, 45. And then to get the sum between position 1 and 5 is  `s[4]-s[0]` 5 - 0 so 5. Let me know if I can make it any more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has better time complexity, but it's more "lodashy":

```
_.map(colB, function(b) { 
    return _.defaults({ value: _(colA).filter(function(a) { 
        return a.point >= b.min && a.point < b.max; 
    }).sumBy('value') }, b);
});
```

- [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) returns a new array, with new objects (no side effects)
- [defaults()](https://lodash.com/docs#defaults) is used to assign the new `value` to the object from `colB`.
- [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) finds the objects from `colA` that fit the current `colB` object.
- [sumBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy) computes the sum, based on the `value` property.

Comment: Definitely is more "lodashy"! However, as you suggested might be the case - it didn't have any better time complexity...