# How to compare two arrays and insert it in update or create array

Tags: jquery

I have got two arrays by name changedemployeesarray and allemployees .

```
var changedemployeesarray = [
  {
    "empId": "1126",
    "name": "sam"
  },
  {
    "empId": "1128",
    "name": "mike"
  },
  {
    "empId": "1134",
    "name": "steve"
  }
]


var allemployees = [
  {
    "empFullName": "sam Raj",
    "empInfo": {
      "empSeq": "1126",
      "createDate": "2018-10-17"
    },
    "modfiedDate": "2018-10-24"
  },
  {
    "empFullName": "mike",
    "empInfo": {
      "empSeq": "1128",
      "createDate": "2018-10-17"
    },
    "modfiedDate": "2018-10-24"
  },
  {
    "empFullName": "steve",
    "empInfo": {
      "empSeq": "1134",
      "createDate": "2018-10-17"
    },
    "modfiedDate": "2018-10-24"
  }
]
```

In case the empId of changedemployeesarray exists/found inside the allemployees array, I want to insert into  updatearray .
If not found insert it under the createarray

I have followed this approach, is there any better way of doing

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/74296/

**expected output**

updatearray

```
[{"empId":"1126","name":"sam"},{"empId":"1128","name":"mike"}]
```

createarray

```
[{"empId":"1136","name":"steve"}]
```

Comment: @Pawan - Do check on complexity. Here is a link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771854/linear-complexity-and-quadratic-complexity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get your 2 array.

```js
var changedemployeesarray = [
  {
    "empId": "1126",
    "name": "sam"
  },
  {
    "empId": "1128",
    "name": "mike"
  },
  {
    "empId": "1136",
    "name": "steve"
  }
]


var allemployees = [
  {
    "empFullName": "sam Raj",
    "empInfo": {
      "empSeq": "1126",
      "createDate": "2018-10-17"
    },
    "modfiedDate": "2018-10-24"
  },
  {
    "empFullName": "mike",
    "empInfo": {
      "empSeq": "1128",
      "createDate": "2018-10-17"
    },
    "modfiedDate": "2018-10-24"
  },
  {
    "empFullName": "steve",
    "empInfo": {
      "empSeq": "1134",
      "createDate": "2018-10-17"
    },
    "modfiedDate": "2018-10-24"
  }
]
  var updatearray = [];
var createarray = [];

updatearray = changedemployeesarray.filter(a=> allemployees.some(b=> b.empInfo.empSeq === a.empId));
createarray = changedemployeesarray.filter(a=> !allemployees.some(b=> b.empInfo.empSeq === a.empId));

console.log("updatearray",updatearray)
console.log("createarray",createarray)
```

Comment: thanks , is it possible to have the expected output format also ??

Comment: @Pawan, woops the array sequence was wrong, check updated answer

Comment: @Justcode - I believe that the solution has `quadratic complexity`. Isn't it?

Comment: what is the `.filter(a=>allemployees.some(b=> b)` in your code It looks like lambda expression in c#

Comment: I want to learn this in jquery so please give me links where i can learn it

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Yes, I think for the huge data.

Comment: @Justcode - Actually that was the point as the OP was looking for a more efficient solution. Anyways the solution posted is accepted by OP, hence, it has to be the best of lot. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can try following. It solves the problem in **linear complexity**.

- Create an object from `changedemployeesarray`
- Now iterate over `allemployees` and populate `updatearray` on match and delete entry from object created above
- All the remaining entries in `obj` are missing i.e. `created`. Populate `createarray` with that.

```js
var changedemployeesarray = [{"empId":"1126","name":"sam"},{"empId":"1128","name":"mike"},{"empId":"1136","name":"steve"}];
var allemployees = [{"empFullName":"sam Raj","empInfo":{"empSeq":"1126","createDate":"2018-10-17"},"modfiedDate":"2018-10-24"},{"empFullName":"mike","empInfo":{"empSeq":"1128","createDate":"2018-10-17"},"modfiedDate":"2018-10-24"},{"empFullName":"steve","empInfo":{"empSeq":"1134","createDate":"2018-10-17"},"modfiedDate":"2018-10-24"}];

// Step 1 - Create object from changedemployeesarray
let obj = changedemployeesarray.reduce((a,c) => Object.assign(a, {[c.empId] : c}), {});

// Step 2 - Populate updatearray in case of match
let updatearray = allemployees.reduce((a,c) => {
  if(obj[c.empInfo.empSeq]) {
    a.push(obj[c.empInfo.empSeq]);
    delete obj[c.empInfo.empSeq];
  }
  return a;
}, []);
// Step 3 - Populate createarray with remaining values (missing means created)
let createarray = Object.values(obj);
console.log(createarray);
console.log(updatearray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have UNIQUE key as "empid" then Best practice is to create a single array and use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" in backend .. It will update entry if empid is already existing.